# All categories are not showing in Manage products?

Tags: php, magento

After I click on Edit link in product grid. In categories section I am getting only one category. But I have lots of categories in store.

If I am going to add new product, all categories are showing.

[image: ss1]

Existing product, If I want to change subcategories. Its just showing only one always for every existing products.

[image: ss2]

Comment: What's the problem? You did notice the scrollbar on the right side?

Comment: @AndréSchild, Problem is, for every product I am getting KIA as category. It should not come.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these categories are not visible in the same storeview that the product is.